# Php query for logged in users and not logged in users between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to query which shows all active users (Logged in Users) between two dates. When ever a user logs in the date is recorded in last_login field. The query is below and its working fine;

```
select * from users where (users.last_login BETWEEN '" . $fromdate . "' AND  '" . $todate . "')
```

Now i am trying to query which shows all Inactive Users (Not Logged in Users) between two dates. I am not sure how i will modify the existing query to achieve this condition. Can anyone pls help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to write the inverse logic, I think this will do the job:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_login NOT BETWEEN '" . $fromdate . "' AND '" . $todate . "'"
```

*note if these variables are coming from user input, you should be using prepared statements and placeholders for security/stability.